# Calendar ID in linq

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, linq, calendar

I try to get calendar ID in LINQ .. So I try this query

```
T1 ts = new T1();
var list1 = ts.table2.ToList();
var list1 = ts.table2.ToList();
var dq = (from reg_data in list1
          join re in ts.table1 on reg_Data.RID equals re.RID
          where reg_data.RID == Convert.ToInt32(regiondrop.SelectedValue)
          || (re.startdate == fromdate.Value && re.enddate == todate.Value)
          orderby reg_data.OName
          select new
          {
              ID = reg_data.ID,
              OName = reg_data.OName,
              RegNo = reg_data.RegNo,
              RID = reg_data.RID
          }).ToList();
GridView1.DataSource = dq;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

But there is error in `fromdate` and `todate`:

> The name 'todate' does not exist in the current context
>
> The name 'fromdate' does not exist in the current context

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ID="fromdate" /> 
<input type="text" ID="todate" />
```

So how I get this `fromdate` and `todate` in query?

Any solution please?

Comment: Try to use proper tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make HTML elements in ASP.NET programmable, add a `runat="server"` attribute to the HTML element:

```
<input type="text" ID="fromdate" runat="server"/>
```

Also you could use [Server Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386416.aspx) for this purpose instead.